# How to make manifest for cashing when I use angular2-webpack-starter?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, manifest, manifest.cache

I am using [angular2 webpack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) for my project.

And now I want to cache some images.
This starter has `manifest.json`, maybe it is for this purpose?

Or it has the same name like [manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) for cashing?